# Use file A with number IDs to extract 23th column from file B rows matching the IDs

Tags: text-processing, command-line, awk

I want to use file A (fileA.txt) with 233 IDs (four numbers, first column) to extract the 23th column from file B, but only from rows (first column also) that match the file A ID

I've tried:

```
 awk 'NR==FNR{ a[$0]++; next }{ if ($23 in a) {$0=$23; print}}' FileA.txt fileB.txt > fileC.txt
```

Comment: Please provide a specific example of each input file and the desired output.  Also, what have you tried, and how did it not work as you intended or expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly,  you are going to match IDs in column1 from fileA.txt with IDs in column23 in fileB.txt and if matched print the column23 from fileB.txt, if no, please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/382259/edit) your question with more details.

I assume your files are looks like this:

```
==> fileA.txt <==
1111 column2 column3 column4 ...
2222 c1 c2 c3 c4 ...
4444 co1 co2 co3 co4 ...
3333 col1 col2 col3 col4 ...
```

```
==> fileB.txt <==
c11 ... c22 3333 c24 c25
co11 ... co22 0000 co24 co25
col11 ... col22 4444 col24 col25
```

then the command would be as follow:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {seen[$1]++;next;} ($23 in seen){print $23}' fileA.txt fileB.txt
```

the output which is from fileB.txt

```
c11
col11
```